# how to send data using foreachRDD using Java

Tags: java, streaming, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am having RDD data which I converted in JavaDStream ,now I want to send it to kafka topic,
I don't want kafka sending code,
just I need foreachRDD implementation,
my code is look like as

```
public void publishtoKafka(ITblStream t)
    {
        MyTopicProducer MTP = ProducerFactory.createProducer(hostname+":"+port);
        JavaDStream<?> rdd = (JavaDStream<?>) t.getRDD();

        rdd.foreachRDD(new Function<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
             KafkaUtils.sendDataAsString(MTP,topicName, "String RDDData");
            return null;
            }
          });
        log.debug("------------------------sent to kafka: ------------------");

    }
```

here myTopicproducer will create producer which is working fine
 KafkaUtils.sendDataAsString is method which will publish data to kafka topic is also working fine,

I have only one problem I am not able to convert JavaDStream rdd as string using foreach or foreachRDD finally I need String message from rdds,
kindly suggest java code only and I dont want to use anonymous classes,

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test that, but should work fine:

```
public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
    for (rddData : rdd.collect()) {
        KafkaUtils.sendDataAsString(MTP,topicName, rddData);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The point is you have to `collect` your RDD ([javadoc here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#collect())) to get the actual collection of String data from your RDD.

Comment: @serejja-its not working please can you send me only the part to send JavaDStream RDD using foreachRDD using Function Call,rest I will manipulate.

Comment: Can you specify what is not working? Its usually easier for other if you specify what is the error you are getting when you say "its not working".

Comment: @Tathagata Das- when I am trying to send  JavaDStream<?> rdd as above in my code , data not publishing in kafka topic, as well as I have tried as per serejja comment as well

Comment: collect() brings all the messages back to the driver program -- would it be better to use foreach() so that it runs in parallel on the executors?

Answer (score 1):

issue has bee resolved, 
when I used

```
rdd.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() { 
                @Override 
                public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception { 
                if(rdd!=null) 
            {   
            List<String> result = rdd.collect(); 
            KafkaUtil.sendString(p,topic,result.get(0)); 
 KafkaUtils.sendDataAsString(MTP,topicName, result.get(0)); 

            }
```